# EF Core: Juggling between cascading cycles and conflicting property with simple name

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to a create a many-to-many relationship by using a linking table `Booking` and this got me stuck juggling between two errors and I'm very confused.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Bookings_WorkProfiles_WorkProfileId' on table 'Bookings' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Which I tried to solve going into `Context` class `modelBuilder`.

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                .HasOne(e => e.UserProfile)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

But this creates the following error:

> The foreign key property 'Booking.UserProfileId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'UserProfileId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

I am very confused. I tried fixing this error by removing the foreign key etc. and I get back to first error again.

What I would like: deleting `UserProfile` or `WorkProfile` to not cascade to delete booking so I don't get the the first error.

```cs
public class Booking : BaseDateClass
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdvertTreatmentId")]
    public AdvertTreatment AdvertTreatment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkProfileId")]
    public WorkProfile WorkProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile : BaseDateClass
{
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class WorkProfile : BaseDateClass
{
    public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkAccountId")]
    public WorkAccount WorkAccount { get; set; }
    public List<Advert>? Adverts { get; set; }
    public List<WorkProfileLanguage> WorkProfileLanguages { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: this is an Entity Framework Core 6.0.5 project

```cs
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second problem is caused by a typical mistake with fluent relationship configuration.

You are required to start the relationship configuration with `Has{One|Many}` followed by `With{One|Many}`, but when doing so, many people don't realize that not passing the navigation property to these fluent calls does not mean "use the conventional default", but instead it means that the relationship has **no** navigation property at the corresponding end.

However, when you *do* have navigation property, this leaves it unmapped, which in turn causes EF to associate a different separate relationship with conventional FK name. Which in turn leads to errors like the one in question, and in general is not what you want.

Thus, you should always pass the correct argument to `Has` / `With` method.

In your case, the cause of the issue is the `HasMany()` call here

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                .HasOne(e => e.UserProfile)
                .WithMany() // <--
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

which leaves `UserProfile.Bookings` collection navigation property unmapped.

So change it to

```cs
.WithMany(e => e.Bookings)
```

and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem that your are defining the FK in attributes and then FluentApi is trying to add another. using by-convention value which will be the same as the item specified via attributes.

Try removing:

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
```

from your class and update your Fluent config to:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
    .HasOne(e => e.UserProfile)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForiegnKey("UserProfileId")
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

**UPDATE**

I guess that your other relationships are causing some issues.

Using the following model without any Fluent Config:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkProfileId")]
    public WorkProfile WorkProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class WorkProfile
{
    public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

I get a migration created without problem and am able to update to an Sql Server database.

Migration created is:

```
public partial class initial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "UserProfile",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_UserProfile", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "WorkProfile",
            columns: table => new
            {
                WorkProfileId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_WorkProfile", x => x.WorkProfileId);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Bookings",
            columns: table => new
            {
                BookingId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                UserProfileId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                WorkProfileId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Bookings", x => x.BookingId);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Bookings_UserProfile_UserProfileId",
                    column: x => x.UserProfileId,
                    principalTable: "UserProfile",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Bookings_WorkProfile_WorkProfileId",
                    column: x => x.WorkProfileId,
                    principalTable: "WorkProfile",
                    principalColumn: "WorkProfileId",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Bookings_UserProfileId",
            table: "Bookings",
            column: "UserProfileId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Bookings_WorkProfileId",
            table: "Bookings",
            column: "WorkProfileId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Bookings");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "UserProfile");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "WorkProfile");
    }
}
```

**Alternative**

```
public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]  // REMOVED
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkProfileId")]
    public WorkProfile WorkProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class WorkProfile
{
    public int WorkProfileId { get; set; }
    public List<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
    : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }    

    public DbSet<WorkProfile> WorkProfiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<Booking>()
            .HasOne(b => b.UserProfile)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("UserProfileId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}

also works fine.
```

**Just noticed the signature of your OnModelCreating!!**

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

Change that to match the signature in my latest post.

Comment: I deleted the foreignKey attribute and added the fluentAPI but I am still getting the conflicting property with simple name error

Comment: Do you have any other FluentApi configuration that we can't see here.  Perhaps on the UserProfile entity?

Comment: nope, the only fluentAPI I am using is the one in your answer.

Comment: See my update.  I think you might have to remove some relationships and build them up again until you find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: See my latest update.  I don't think your OnModelCreating was being called due to incorrect signature, unless that partial stuff is something I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I am still getting the simple name error. My codebase is matching yours. The partial stuff is to not have your code deleted when your run code generators that generated context file. It is to extract the implementation of the onModelCreating method to another file. I am gonna set up a completely new project tomorrow (heading to sleep now) and see if it still produce same error to be sure.

Comment: PS.  I get the same error as you when I remove the Attribute for UserProfileId and DO NOT have any Fluent Config.  When I add the Fluent Config all is fine.  This is why I now think the issue is that your Fluent Config is not being executed due to the function signature.